# 3rd Wed of Mar / Jun / Sep / Dec

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to build a function on Excel VBA to get the 3rd Wed of Mar / Jun / Sep / Fri, depending which is closer to the specified date. Suppose today is 6/2/2019, then it should return 6/19/2019, and if it's 6/19/2019, it should return 9/18/2019, and so forth. However, the code does not work. I have attached the code below for your purview. Thank you!

```
Function NextIMMDate(ByVal dteFromDate As Date) As Date

    Call getNextIMMDate(dteFromDate)

    dayBool = (Day(dteFromDate) < Day(NextIMMDate))
    monthBool = (Month(dteFromDate) = Month(NextIMMDate))

    If (dayBool And monthBool) Or (Not dayBool And Not monthBool) Or (dayBool And Not monthBool) Then
        Call getNextIMMDate(dteFromDate)
    Else
        useDate = DateSerial(Year(dteFromDate), Month(dteFromDate), 21)
        Call getNextIMMDate(useDate)
    End If

End Function

Sub getNextIMMDate()

    Const lngMONTHS_PER_ROLL As Long = 3
    Const lngDAY As Long = 20

    Dim lngMonth As Long
    Dim NextIMMDate As Date

'    dteFromDate = Range("B13")

    lngMonth = -Int((-Month(dteFromDate) - IIf(Day(dteFromDate) > lngDAY, 1, 0)) _
                    / lngMONTHS_PER_ROLL) * lngMONTHS_PER_ROLL

    NextDate = DateSerial(Year(dteFromDate), lngMonth, lngDAY)

    If Weekday(NextDate) = vbWednesday Then
        lngROLL_DAY = 20
    ElseIf Weekday(NextDate) = vbMonday Then
        lngROLL_DAY = 15
    ElseIf Weekday(NextDate) = vbTuesday Then
        lngROLL_DAY = 21
    ElseIf Weekday(NextDate) = vbThursday Then
        lngROLL_DAY = 19
    ElseIf Weekday(NextDate) = vbFriday Then
        lngROLL_DAY = 18
    ElseIf Weekday(NextDate) = vbSaturday Then
        lngROLL_DAY = 17
    ElseIf Weekday(NextDate) = vbSunday Then
        lngROLL_DAY = 16
    End If

    NextIMMDate = DateSerial(Year(dteFromDate), lngMonth, lngROLL_DAY)

'    Range("B31") = NextIMMDate

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Without particularly reading your code, from what you are describing, the logic should be something like: 1. decide what date is the 3rd Wednesday, every 3 months. 2. Compare the given date to these, and find the first one that's > than given date. Please correct me if I'm wrong.. i`ll try to write something up based on this logic.

Comment: @DaRXyde yes exactly, that's the point. There's a caveat though: if it's on the date of the 3rd Wed of Mar/Jun/Sep/Dec, it should return the next date of 3rd Wed of Mar/Jun/Sep/Dec. i.e. 6/19/2019 should return 9/18/2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might need some tweaking, but it should get you on the right path i guess. I've used a function from vbaexpress.com, which does most of the job to be honest. My part is only handling your logic.

```vb
Public Function NextIMMDate(ByVal dteFromDate As Date) As Date

Const nthPosition As Long = 3 'Third week
Const dayIndex As Long = 4 'Wednesday
Dim targetYear As Long

Dim X As Long
Dim arrMonths(1 To 4) As Long: For X = 1 To 4: arrMonths(X) = X * 3: Next X
Dim arrDates(1 To 4) As Date

targetYear = Year(dteFromDate)

For X = LBound(arrMonths) To UBound(arrMonths)
    If X = UBound(arrMonths) Then
        'handle next year?
        arrDates(X) = NthWeekday(nthPosition, dayIndex, 3, targetYear + 1)
    Else
        arrDates(X) = NthWeekday(nthPosition, dayIndex, arrMonths(X), targetYear)
    End If

    If arrDates(X) > dteFromDate Then
        NextIMMDate = arrDates(X)
        Exit For
    End If
Next X

End Function

Public Function NthWeekday(Position, dayIndex As Long, targetMonth As Long, Optional targetYear As Long)
     'Source: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=814
     '****************************************************************

     ' Returns any arbitrary weekday (the "Nth" weekday) of a given month
     ' Position is the weekday's position in the month.  Must be a number 1-5, or the letter L (last)
     ' DayIndex is weekday: 1=Sunday, 2=Monday, ..., 7=Saturday
     ' TargetMonth is the month the date is in: 1=Jan, 2=Feb, ..., 12=Dec
     ' If TargetYear is omitted, year for current system date/time is used

     ' This function as written supports Excel.  To support Access, replace instances of
     ' CVErr(xlErrValue) with Null.  To use with other VBA-supported applications or with VB,
     ' substitute a similar value

    Dim FirstDate As Date

     ' Validate DayIndex
    If dayIndex < 1 Or dayIndex > 7 Then
        NthWeekday = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If targetYear = 0 Then targetYear = Year(Now)

    Select Case Position

         'Validate Position
    Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "L", "l"

         ' Determine date for first of month
        FirstDate = DateSerial(targetYear, targetMonth, 1)

         ' Find first instance of our targeted weekday in the month
        If Weekday(FirstDate, vbSunday) < dayIndex Then
            FirstDate = FirstDate + (dayIndex - Weekday(FirstDate, vbSunday))
        ElseIf Weekday(FirstDate, vbSunday) > dayIndex Then
            FirstDate = FirstDate + (dayIndex + 7 - Weekday(FirstDate, vbSunday))
        End If

         ' Find the Nth instance.  If Position is not numeric, then it must be "L" for last.
         ' In that case, loop to find last instance of the month (could be the 4th or the 5th)
        If IsNumeric(Position) Then
            NthWeekday = FirstDate + (Position - 1) * 7
            If Month(NthWeekday) <> Month(FirstDate) Then NthWeekday = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Else
            NthWeekday = FirstDate
            Do Until Month(NthWeekday) <> Month(NthWeekday + 7)
                NthWeekday = NthWeekday + 7
            Loop
        End If

         ' This only comes into play if the user supplied an invalid Position argument
    Case Else
        NthWeekday = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I have tried modifying your code to fit the December case in, however I have no luck. Is there a way to do so? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a worksheet formula:

```
=IF(A1<EDATE(A1-DAY(A1)+1,2-MOD(MONTH(A1)-1,3))+21-WEEKDAY(EDATE(A1-DAY(A1)+1,2-MOD(MONTH(A1)-1,3))+3),
EDATE(A1-DAY(A1)+1,2-MOD(MONTH(A1)-1,3))+21-WEEKDAY(EDATE(A1-DAY(A1)+1,2-MOD(MONTH(A1)-1,3))+3),
EDATE(A1-DAY(A1)+1,5-MOD(MONTH(A1)-1,3))+21-WEEKDAY(EDATE(A1-DAY(A1)+1,5-MOD(MONTH(A1)-1,3))+3))
```

---

### Algorithm

- Calculate the next (or current) quarterly 1st of the month:

---

```
EDATE(A1-DAY(A1)+1,2-MOD(MONTH(A1)-1,3))
                   ^ (change to 5 for three months later)
```

- Calculate the third Wednesday of that month:

---

```
+21-WEEKDAY(EDATE(A1-DAY(A1)+1,2-MOD(MONTH(A1)-1,3))+3)
```

- If the original date is less than that calculated date, use that, otherwise add three months and calculate the appropriate third Wednesday

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Build an array of 'third Wednesday quarterlies' and use the worksheet's Match function to find the appropriate one from the input date.

```
Option Explicit

Function NextThirdWednesdayQuarter(dt As Long)

    Dim i As Long, m As Long, y As Long
    ReDim dts(0) As Variant

    'building the 'third Wednesday' doesn't take long
    'you should never need more than Mar, Jun, Sep, Dec for
    'the current year and the next year of input date
    'descending order for the worksheet match function
    For y = Year(dt) + 1 To Year(dt) Step -1
        'for Mar, Jun, Sep, Dec
        For m = 12 To 3 Step -3
            'third Wednesday in m and y
            dts(UBound(dts)) = CLng(DateSerial(y, m, 22 - Weekday(DateSerial(y, m, 0), vbWednesday)))
            'make room for next
            ReDim Preserve dts(UBound(dts) + 1)
        Next m
    Next y

    'remove last unused array element
    ReDim Preserve dts(UBound(dts) - 1)

    'add noon to input date so equals won't match
    'worksheet's Match in descending order gives position of date from array
    NextThirdWednesdayQuarter = dts(Application.Match(dt + 0.5, dts, -1) - 1)

    'don't forget to format the UDF worksheet cell as a date

End Function
```

IDK if your own code handled input dates on or after the third Wednesday in December but this one will push it to the next third Wednesday in the following March.